# How to do language representation on huge documents of 3000-4000 word for query-based retrieval?

Tags: search, nlp, gensim, cosine-similarity, doc2vec

I am trying to implement a semantic search to retrieve similar documents from a dataset of unstructured French documents.

- These documents are not categorized and are templates with 300 - 3000 words per document.
- I am using doc2vec using gensim to find the paragraph embeddings with 300 dimensions and a window of 5 of the dataset.
- I am then converting the search query which is a maximum of 5 words to the vector with 300 dimensions and comparing the cosine distance to find the document close to the search queries.

I am not getting good results. Please suggest some strategies to do the semantic search. I was trying to reduce the number of words in my dataset by doing rake keyword extraction.

Comment: Without seeing your training code, it's unclear if you might be making some common mistakes in corpus-handling, training-parameters, or training code. Without seeing your code for turning a query into a vector, that could be going wrong, too. Can you edit your question to show more of your coding choices, & exactly what process gives results that are "not good"?

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment. I will upload the code on github and share the link with you if that works better.

Comment: Boiling it down to small fragments that fit well into your question here is much better than uploading it elsewhere. The key things to show: (1) how is your corpus prepped; (2) what parameters are you passing to `Doc2Vec`, & what model functions are you using to train the model; (3) what process/methods are you using to prep queries & select similar documents.

Comment: But to give you a fair idea:

Comment: But to give you a fair idea: My model training has the following steps 1) data cleaning 2) tokenization of words 3) stop word removal using nltk 4) stemming and model training with gensim doc2vec. I am training the model for 400 epochs, 5 window size, and vector_size 300. For the query I am pre-processing it and changing it into the word vector. And comparing cosine similarity distance between the document and the query.

Comment: Yes, there are some errors that people commonly make in all of those steps – seeing the code, to know how you've done it, is the only way to work out what might be your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for your poor result if the queries are just too short to be embedded by  doc2vec. If you only care about performance, I would recommend using some off-the-shelf information retrieval tools like Lucene.

If you want to play with neural nets and embeddings, you can do the following:

- Just use word embedding, e.g., from [FastText](https://fasttext.cc/). Remove stop words both in the query and the documents and represent them with the average word embedding and do the comparison by cosine distance.
- If you don't care about efficiency a lot, you can also try multilingual BERT (available in the [Transformers](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers) library) or brand new French model called [CamemBERT](https://camembert-model.fr/). In this case, you would just take the `[cls]` vectors and do the cosine distance on them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just to clarify my understanding trying word2vec instead of doc2vec with pre-trained word vectors can help produce better results?

Comment: Both Camembert and word embedding worked better for this model.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with indexing your documents in [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/install-elasticsearch.html). Their out-of-the-box methods with TF-IDF are pretty great.

If you're looking to do more sophisticated "semantic search" using neural networks, I would recommend [NBoost](https://github.com/koursaros-ai/nboost). You can just `pip install nboost` and it will create a semantic search engine out of the Elasticsearch.